# Vue-Select reduce is not working - Showing ID instead of the label

Tags: vue.js

I am using this vue select https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting for the dropdown countries. Here is the code:

```
<v-select
    v-model="project_data.country"
    :options="project_data.countries"
    :reduce="country => country.value" 
    label="label"
    :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
/>
```

This `project_data.country` value is : 5
This `project_data.countries` value is array of object. Something like :

```
[
    { value : 1, label : Dhaka },
    { value : 2, label : India },
    and so on ......
]
```

Now on my local, I can see the label on the dropdown **BUT** when I complied the code using :

```
npm run prod
```

and **compressed** the whole project and **upload** to live server then I can see the **ID** instead of the **label**. Something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why? I am spending tooooo many hours to figure it out :( :( :(

My goal is to get the **single ID value** from the dropdown **( I can )** and save it to the database and then again show the label **( I can't )** based on the **single ID value**.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with that select and its in the Docs, its that you need to make sure that the value for v-model:
If options has by example only these 2:

```
[
    { value : 1, label : Dhaka },
    { value : 2, label : India }
]
```

and `project_data.country` is `3` the select will show the value `3` since the Vue Select searched for it and didnt find it.

So make sure in prod you have `5` in the list of countries.

Comment: I gave you example of the array of object. I have 300 item on this array of object. So, that 5 is must exist.

Comment: @Shibbir go to the network tab in the developer tools and check the payload